# jQuery .each() with string

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

How do I use jQuery .each() on a string

```
// For Exmaple

var mystring = '<div> bleh content </div> <div> bleh content </div>';

$('div', mystring).each(function(e) {
  alert('do something');
});
```

// the above code isnt launching an alert for each div in the string?  Im not sure why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you're doing it, you're searching for `div` elements inside the elements passed in. Basically equivalent of doing a `.find()`.

What you want is `filter()` which will filter over the top level elements in the collection you passed.

**Test it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/u5uDg/

```
var mystring = '<div> bleh content </div> <div> bleh content </div>';

$(mystring).filter('div').each(function(e) {
    alert('do something');
});
```

If you wanted to use your approach, you would need to give the `div` elements a parent on which jQuery can perform the find.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5uDg/1/

```
      // Added parent <div> element
var mystring = '<div><div> bleh content </div> <div> bleh content </div></div>';

$('div', mystring).each(function(e) {
  alert('do something');
});
```

---

As requested in your comment, you can delay execution of the code in the `.each()` using `setTimeout()` and arriving at the duration of each by multiplying the current iteration number by the number of milliseconds you want to delay.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5uDg/6/

```
var mystring = '<div> bleh content </div> <div> bleh content </div>';

   // Get the length
var length = $(mystring).filter('div').length;

$(mystring).filter('div').each(function(e) {
    // setTimeout is used to delay code from executing.
    // Here we multiply e (which is the index of the current 
    //   iteration) by 2000 milliseconds, so each iteration
    //   is delayed by an additional 2000ms
    (function(th) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                 alert($(th).text());
                 if(!--length) { alert('done'); } // alert if done
        }, e * 2000);
    }(this));
});​
```

Comment: Pattrick thanks so much, 1 more question how would i put a like 2 second delay so .delay('200'); on each of those callbacks.  So for every div in mystring, alert('do something'); every 2 seconds.

Comment: @kr1zmo - Sorry, just saw your comments. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: @kr1zmo - You can create a closure, and pass it in: `(function(th) { setTimeout(function() {alert($(th).text());}, e * 2000); }(this));` I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Awesome pattrick one more thing, how do I run something after all the intervals have completed and all the alerts went off.

Comment: @kr1zmo - You'll need to find out how many iterations there will be `var length = $(mystring).filter('div').length;` , then inside the `setTimeout()` decrement `length` and check to see if it was the last. `if(!--length) {  alert('done'); }`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your intent, the jQuery code will look different.

To iterate through divs with content, the divs need not be assigned to a variable in the javascript. They can just live in the html:

```html
<div class="mystring">bleh content</div>
<div class="mystring">blehhh content</div>
```

Then, your script will look like the below and you should see the alerts:

```js
$('div.mystring').each(function(e) {
  alert('do something');
});
```

If you are trying to iterate through a mystring array, your code would look like this:

```js
var mystring = '<div class="mystring">bleh content</div><div class="mystring">blehhh content</div>';
$.each(mystring, function(e) {
  alert('do something');
});
```