# .each trough html inside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

He I am just asking how to use .each when my html is inside java-script variable and not in the DOM itself.

If I have html like this:

```
<html>
    <h1>deze</h1>
    <h1>this</h1>
    <h1>dies</h1>
</html>
```

I can do:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});
```

It will just give a alert 3 times telling deze, this, dies.
Now I want to do the same but then with html inside variable. No idea how this is my pseudo  code:

```
var html = '
           <h1>deze</h1>
           <h1>this</h1>
           <h1>dies</h1>
           ';

$(html).each('h1', function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});
```

Not sure how to do this I have no idea. Please enlighten me!

Comment: Your html variable is invalid. Your use of each is invalid.

Comment: There is another topic who have a good response.
See [Stackoverflow Topic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153940/jquery-each-with-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eqifed/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
var html = '<h1>deze</h1>'+
           '<h1>this</h1>'+
           '<h1>dies</h1>';

$(html).filter(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                          // deze // this // dies
});
```

Comment: Why in the world do you have a get(0)? It does nothing to help.

Comment: Yes I already using your peace of code and I just removed the .get(0) Because I saw no reason to call a ajax function on that spot.

Comment: @roXon The reason I need this is because I use .post to get some html and then I need illiterate over the root elements inside there. So your code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out to parse your sting into some DOM nodes first:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

```
var html = '<div>\
           <h1>deze</h1>\
           <h1>this</h1>\
           <h1>dies</h1>\
           </div>';
var test = $.parseHTML(html);

$('h1',test).each(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});
```

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnWqQ/3/

Also, in your question I noticed  that your html variable won't parse into a variable the way it is typed onto multiple lines.

One thing to watch out for when using this method is that it won't work if the element that you are searching for is at the top level. to avoid this, just wrap your string in a div. for more info on this see here: http://fredwu.me/post/554746690/jquery-tip-traverse-parse-html-string

Comment: I like your answer to, .filter works for me but to know how to use html inside variable is handy thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '\
           <h1>deze</h1>\
           <h1>this</h1>\
           <h1>dies</h1>\
           ';

$("<div/>").html(html).find("h1").each(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});


$(html).filter("h1").each(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like:

```
$(html).filter('h1').each(function(){
    var test = $(this).html();
    alert(test);                
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7f3F/

Comment: Did you try it? You will get no alerts.

Comment: My bad... try it now.  `filter`, not `find`.